# useEffect async function wont run on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

The function getImages is suppose to run once only on page load.

When i refresh the page the both tempQuestionImages and questionImages is empty. But when a hot reload is done it works perfectly.

I use nextJs and firebase,cloud storage if that helps

```js
useEffect(() => {
    async function getImages() {
        await list(storageFolder, { maxResults: 10 }).then((res) => {
            res.items.forEach((item) => {
                tempQuestionImages.push(item.fullPath)
            })
        })
    
        tempQuestionImages.forEach((url) => {
            getDownloadURL(ref(firebaseStorage,url)).then((downUrl) => {
                questionImages[questionImages.length] = downUrl
                setQuestionImages([...questionImages])  
            })
            setLoading(false)
        }) 
    }
    getImages()
}, [])
```

any kind of help is much appriciated!

## Update

So after following the [example](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useEffect#fetching-data-with-effects) linked I did this.

```js
useEffect(() => { 
    const storageFolder = ref(firebaseStorage,`/papers/${paper}`)
    async function getImages() {
        setTestList([])
       
        const result = await (await list(storageFolder, { maxResults: 10 })).items.map((item) => { return [...item.fullPath] })
        if (!ignore){
            console.log(result)
            setTestList(result)
        }
    }
       
    let ignore = false
    getImages()

    return () => {
        ignore = true
    }  
}, [])
```

But still i get the same result. result console logs as an empty array on refresh, but logs as an array with 6 items when hot reload.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you saying that your state should be preserved when you refresh the page?

Comment: How do you know that they are empty? If you are trying to console.log right after the setQuestionImages() it won't show up because useState is also async.

Comment: What i want to do is to have an array with all the links to some images in google cloud on page load. I have managed to add a button and add a onclick with all the above logic and it works fine. But i want that array right after the page load automatically and i cant make it work

Comment: @crunchytoast they aren't suppose to be empty. If you mean how do i know if the aren't empty, i can run this code without the useeffect hook ( with a button with on click for example) and it works fine.

Comment: Effects run after the render. So your variables will be empty/null on initial render, then the effect will run and a new render will fire off. Is this what you're seeing?

Comment: @Nikki9696 I think so. any workaround?

Comment: @TharushaJayasooriya - it's by design. Check your variables for null before using them. https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects

Comment: Here's a fetch example https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useEffect#fetching-data-with-effects

Comment: Just because you mentioned hot reload, please note that some functionality like caching doesn't work correctly in dev environment because of how hot reload and similar things work. Maybe deploy a version of your app in Vercel, or do a local build then test in prod environment?

Answer (score 1):

Guess you should not keep the `!ignore` condition logic inside your async function (otherwise, it will be part of the same promise)

Try the below code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let ignore = false

    const storageFolder = ref(firebaseStorage, `/papers/${paper}`)
    const getImages = async () => {
        const result = await (await list(storageFolder, { maxResults: 10 })).items.map((item) => { return [...item.fullPath] })
        return result
    }
    
    getImages().then(data => {
        if (!ignore) {
            setTestList(data)
        }
    })

    return () => {
        ignore = true
    }

}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call for the information for tempQuestionImages and questionImages, it might  have been processed after you are trying to use tempQuestionImages and questionImages. That's why it is empty regularly and working during hot reload.

Answer (score 0):

U should add a conditional statement at the start of your page.
This would make your page wait for data to have the image links before loading your page.
I had a similar issue and this fixed it.
Just put an 'SVG' with loading animation instead of a static span.

```
return(
  <>
    // If 'Data'  does has 'value' then Render Page else 'Loading...'
    {data ? <div>Content</div> : <span>Loading...</span>}
  </>
)
```

Or you could just put it on the image component, making it wait by flashing, youtube often does this if you refresh a page, it shows blank page with outlines, only when they have all the data do they show the video.

Answer (score 0):

**RCA**

The async function `getImages` inside useEffect becomes a javascript closure.

> When i refresh the page the both tempQuestionImages and questionImages is empty.

Hence you get the initial value of `tempQuestionImages` and `questionImages` as empty when a component mounts itself for the first time or when the app is reloaded manually..

> But when a hot reload is done it works perfectly

Whereas, hot reloading allows you to see the changes that you have made in the code without reloading your entire app. Therefore, it doesn't re-mount the component, instead the component re-renders, henceforth, you have an access to the initial value during the re-render.

**The code part**

Never use, expensive functions in `useEffect`, because `useEffect` is mostly to run side-effects, logging, subscribing or pushing events, during the lifecycle of the component.

If the code is not related to component lifecycle, it should not stay in the `useEffect`

Few issues in the `useEffect` code.
0. You are using `await` and `then` together. Please refer how promises work.

1. Avoid expensive `map`. Expensive calculations, should not stay inside useEffect, as it is not related to the component lifecycle here.
2. Avoid expensive `setState`  in `useEffect`, setState itself is asynchronous. You can take a look on algorithm on how react update states using queuing mechanism [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/8e2bde6f2751aa6335f3cef488c05c3ea08e074a/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberClassUpdateQueue.old.js)

RequirementNow as per your requirement, you need to have this called only once, but not on every re-render.

So to do this, create a singleton flag pattern in a different file.

Above code can be wrapped under `useMemo`. Just don't need to create any extra tempQuestionImages variable. You can directly, see the below implementation of getImages. Tweak it accordingly, and there you go.

```js
React.useMemo(()=>{
 
    async getImages(){
       const res = await (...whateever)
       res.items.forEach((item)=>{
       const url = item.fullPath
       getDownloadURL(ref(firebaseStorage,url))
       .then((downUrl) => {
                questionImages[questionImages.length] = downUrl
                setQuestionImages([...questionImages])  
            })
        })
    }
},[firebaseStorage, ...addDependencyBasedOnRequirement]);
```

Comment: You can try using singelton pattern in react for more strict requirements. More info below
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/singleton-design-pattern-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Try console.log(storageFolder), I think that paper variable might be empty after first render. Also try to check network tab in dev tools to make sure that your request succeed. And also you might not want to declare functions in useEffect, I don't think that this is good idea.

In case if you will find out that your paper variable doesn't have expected value and as I understand this value wouldn't change a lot, you can try something like this

```
const getImages = async (storageFolder) {
        const response = await list(storageFolder, { maxResults: 10 })
        const result = response.items.map((item) => { return [...item.fullPath]})

        console.log(result)
        setTestList(result)
    }


useEffect(() => { 
    if (*some condition to check if paper have expected value*) {
        const storageFolder = ref(firebaseStorage,`/papers/${paper}`)
       
        getImages(storageFolder)
    }

}, [paper])
```

Also I didn't get what ignore exactly do here, cause it wouldn't make a request on component dismount, it will just set a variable to true, and after that component mount again, it will became false again, so I removed it.

I also removed double await from your list request.
And one more thing, I remove `setTestList([])` if you need an array as a default value for this state, just set it in `const [testList, setTestList] = useState([])`.

Hope it helps